# Graphing multi-dimensional K-means cluster NLP python

Tags: python, nlp, k-means, scatter-plot, dimensionality-reduction

I have a multidimensional vector designed for an NLP Classifier.

Here's the dataframe (text_df):

[image]

I used a TfidfVectorizer to create the vector:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5,
                          max_features=13000,
                          min_df=5,
                          stop_words='english',
                          use_idf=True,
                          norm=u'l2',
                          smooth_idf=True
                          )

X = tfidf_v.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = text_df.iloc[:,1].values
```

Shape of X is (13834, 2701).

I used 7 clusters for KMeans:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=7,random_state=42)
```

I tried using PCA, but I'm not sure if the graph looks right.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X_pca = PCA(2).fit_transform(X)

plt.scatter(X_pca[:,0],X_pca[:,1],c=y_kmeans)
plt.title("Clusters")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is this normal for NLP based clusters? I was hoping for more distinctive clusters. Is there a way to clean up this cluster graph? (i.e. clearer groupings, distinct boundaries, cluster points closer together, etc.).

Comment: Perhaps this could help?  http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/

Answer (score 0):

K-Means clustering does not work very well on high dimensional data (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_high-dimensional_data#Problems)) and is usually done after Dimensionality Reduction (PCA, in your example).

As an aside, if you aim is to cluster the documents according to their topics, it's worth exploring [topic modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model). Clustering can then be done using the distributions over topics identified by the topic modelling algorithms.

Comment: I used PCA (2-components) and then graphed the result that you see above. I looked over topic modelling and it's outside the scope of what I'm trying to accomplish in this case. I was hoping to make clusters that would group sentences by the author to see if the authors were consistently grouped in each cluster.